# Triggering an apex class when a field is created/modified in an Object

Tags: salesforce

I am new to salesforce and I am trying working on an integration, where I need to send object schema to a third party system. I was able to create a simple apex class to create a JSON message and send it to an end point.

I am trying to figure out how to automate this, meaning.. I want to trigger this apex class when an new field is created or an existing field is modified in a specific custom object.

Created an apex class to generate a JSON with the list of custom fields in the object and their properties. I want to be able to trigger this automatically when object is updated

Answer (score 0):

There's a "you're doing it wrong" element to it. It's metadata, not data, not so easy to trigger from inside Apex. Salesforce has mechanisms for easy pulling of this info, not pushing. External system can call "describes" with [If-Modified-Since](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_describeGlobal.htm), querying EntityDefinition, FieldDefinition with Tooling API...

Even if you pull it off - technically it'll be useless to external system. When you created new field but didn't modify Profiles/Permission Sets yet - attempts to query it will fail. Same error is thrown for genuine syntax errors in SOQL and for "yes, we do have such field but you're not authorised to see it".

If you really want to continue down this path you can look into [scheduling](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_system_schedulable.htm) Apex (say run every 5 minutes, will that be good enough? Class to check EntityDefinition or Setup Audit Trail and send the message if needed)